# С сортировка столбцов матрицы по элементам побочной диагонали

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

В общем, задача: "Упорядочить столбцы массива по уменьшению элементов побочной диагонали". Вообще не пойму, как сделать.

Comment: @izobara, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/u9uqwK5H
Вот, что пока есть. Не пойму непосредственно как сортировать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разбейте задачу на подзадачи. Пусть массив представляет собой матрицу NxN.

Во-первых, подзадача поиска в столбце элемента, лежащего на побочной диагонали. Для i-го столбца таким элементом будет элемент [N - i, i].

Во-вторых, определите функцию для обмена местами двух столбцов массива.

В-третьих, отсортируйте любым алгоритмом столбцы по убыванию элементов, найденные в первом пункте.

Собственно, всё. 
Алгоритм далеко не идеален с точки зрения производительности, К примеру в нем присутствует перестановка столбцов, что само по себе довольно дорогая операция. Поэтому разумнее будет завести дополнительный массив, хранящий в себе индексы столбцов, и сортировать уже его, а затем, исходя из порядка элементов в получившемся отсортированном массиве, поменять порядок столбцов в массиве исходном

Comment: @DreamChild, IMHO после перестановки столбцов в порядке сортировки элементов диагонали они (эти элементы) как раз с диагонали-то "уползут".  

Представьте

     00001
     00050
     00400
     02000
     70000

сортируем 1,5,4,2,7 получаем 1,2,4,5,7 или переставив столбцы

     00001
     05000
     00400
     00020
     70000

Интересная картина.

--

Не уверен, что если переставлять целиком столбцы, то вообще у этой задачи всегда есть решение.

Возможно, требуется именно рассортировать N элементов побочной диагонали, рассматривая ее как одномерный массив?

Comment: @DreamChild, короче, проснулся и на свежую голову сделал.
http://pastebin.com/L1nYq5UB

Comment: @avp кстати да, любопытная ситуация. Тут нужно бы еще определить, что предполагать под сортировкой

Comment: @DreamChild, смотрите мой код. Суть в том, что побочная диагональ рассматривается как одномерный массив. Он сортируется по возрастанию, а вместе с ним в качестве "побочного действия" изменяется порядок столбцов, к которым принадлежат элементы побочной диагонали. В конце диагональ, естественно, перестаёт быть диагональю, но нигде не оговаривается обратное.

Comment: @izobara, наверное это правильное решение. Решение вот такой задачи:

    Переупорядочить столбцы квадратной матрицы так, чтобы элементы побочной диагонали составляли убывающую последовательность.

Только потестируйте программу потщательней.


    Как заполнять массив?
    1. Взять заданный
    2. Случайный массив
    3. Ввести вручную
    2
    4 5 8 4 
    0 0 6 9 
    9 9 9 9 
    4 5 0 0 
    sh: 1: pause: not found
    4 4 8 5 
    0 9 6 0 
    9 9 9 9 
    4 0 0 5 
    avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ 
    
Видите, **не сортирует.**

 (Я добавил `srand(time(0))` в генерацию случайных).